# How to optimize getting the HTTP status code

Tags: php, http-status-codes

I have an array compose of URLs which I need to check their HTTP status code, my problem is, it took some time to display the results and also displays an error about execution time.

Is there a way to make the checking more faster or display the result one by one while its still checking the results, anything you can suggest.

```
<?php

$arrSites = array('http://example1.com/', 'http://example2.com/', 'http://example3.com/', 'http://example4.com/', 'http://example5.com/', 'http://example6.com/', 'http://example7.com/', 'http://example8.com/',);

for($x = 0; $x < count($arrSites); $x++){

echo statusCode($arrSites[$x]);

}


function statusCode($url) { 

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $httpCode;

}
```

Comment: It takes a while to confirm the HTTP response. The error message means that if an error is encountered, in addition to displaying the HTTP response code, an error message is displayed?

Comment: Take a look at multi-cURL...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: @CalosKao error is about execution exceeds max limit..

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla Got it, and Brad's link maybe helpful for you.

Comment: @CalosKao yea im working on it now..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of reactive programming in php. In which you can shoot all the requests to get the status simultaneously rather than one by one. Which in turn help you to get the response faster then what you are doing right now.

Think about ajax call, async-await or promises in jquery? Event loop in NodeJS.

Please find below links which might help you to implement the same with deep dip into the concept as well.

https://www.phproundtable.com/episode/asynchronous-php

https://reactphp.org/

Comment: @Brad can you make a sample please.